# Laravel find data from database until thats is null or retry is finished

Tags: php, laravel

in my web application i want to search in database and when that is null i should store new data, for checking this operation i'm using `do while` statement with another option to check and search from database with limit period as `retry`, like with this code:

```
$retry = 0;
do {
    $feed = $feeds[array_rand($feeds)];
    $history = InstagramActionsHistory::wherePk($feed->pk)->whereActionName('comment')->first();
    $retry++;
} while ($history == null || $retry >= 3);
```

in this code `while` when `$history` is null or `$retry` is bigger than or equals with `3` statement should be break, but it doesn't work correctly

instead of that this code work correctly:

```
$retry = 0;
do {
    $feed = $feeds[array_rand($feeds)];
    $history = InstagramActionsHistory::wherePk($feed->pk)->whereActionName('comment')->first();
    $retry++;
    if ($history == null || $retry >= 3) {
        break;
    }
} while (true);
```

it seems multi condition dont work in while statement

Comment: Here is correction while ($history == null || $retry >= 3);

Comment: please try that first code again.

Comment: @VasimVanzara when `$history` is null `while` statement don't break

Comment: you should use and condition using shortcircuit operator

Comment: since `first()` will return an item or null, you should do `while($history || $retry >= 3)`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: @VasimVanzara yes, worked, correctly

Comment: @Hussein you have right, your code worked

Comment: which one works correctly?

Comment: @VasimVanzara using and condition

Comment: ok thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use logical operator.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

**Modified code**

```
<?php 
$retry = 0;
do {
        $feed = $feeds[array_rand($feeds)];
        $history = InstagramActionsHistory::wherePk($feed->pk)->whereActionName('comment')->first();
        $retry++;
} while ($history && $retry >= 3);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In first case you will get infinity loop, if cycle loop 3 or more times.

So if you want try to fill `$history` at no more, that 3 times, you need to specify condition as: while `$history` is `NULL` and $retry no more, than 3.

```
$retry = 0;
do {
    $feed = $feeds[array_rand($feeds)];
    $history = InstagramActionsHistory::wherePk($feed->pk)->whereActionName('comment')->first();
    $retry++;
} while ($history == null && $retry < 3);
```